# How to merge multiple annotations into single one?

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, openapi, quarkus

I have a RestControllerResource class within which I am adding multiple `@ExampleObject` annotations. I would like to create another custom annotation and add all the `@ExampleObject` to this `CustomAnnotation` so finally my `RestControllerResource` can have only one annotation which is `CustomAnnotation`.

I tried looking into many things but could not find the right solution or some information. Can someone please specify if it's possible to create a single annotation `CustomAnnotation` from multiple `@ExampleObject`?

Following is the current code I have with multiple `@ExampleObject`:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Content;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.ExampleObject;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/api")
public class RestControllerResponse {

    @Path("/generate")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RequestBody(
            content = @Content(
                    examples = {
                            @ExampleObject(name = "Example1", ref = "Example1.json"),
                            @ExampleObject(name = "Example2", ref = "Example2.json")
                    }))
    public String generator(final Map<String, Object> input) throws Exception {
        return "Hello From Generator Method";
    }
}
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
 @RequestBody(
            content = @Content(
                    examples = {
                            @CustomAnnotation()
                    }))
```

Following is my `CustomAnnotation`:

```
@Target({})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

Following is the @ExampleObject:

```
package org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * This object illustrates an example of a particular content
 * 
 * @see <a href= "https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#exampleObject">OpenAPI Specification Example Object</a>
 **/
@Target({})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface ExampleObject {
    /**
     * A unique name to identify this particular example in a map.
     * <p>
     * The name is REQUIRED when the example is defined within {@link org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.Components}. The 
     * name will be used as the key to add this example to the 'examples' map for reuse.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @return the name of this example
     **/
    String name() default "";

    /**
     * A brief summary of the purpose or context of the example
     * 
     * @return a summary of this example
     **/
    String summary() default "";

    /**
     * Long description for the example. 
     * CommonMark syntax MAY be used for rich text representation.
     * 
     * @return a description of this example
     **/
    String description() default "";

    /**
     * A string representation of the example. 
     * <p>
     * This is mutually exclusive with the externalValue property, and ignored if the externalValue property is specified. 
     * </p>
     * If the media type associated with the example allows parsing into an object, it may be converted from a string.
     * @return the value of the example
     **/
    String value() default "";

    /**
     * A URL to point to an external document to be used as an example.
     * This provides the capability to reference examples that cannot easily be included in JSON or YAML documents.
     * <p> 
     * This is mutually exclusive with the value property.
     * </p>
     * @return an external URL of the example
     **/
    String externalValue() default "";

    /**
     * Reference value to an Example object.
     * <p>
     * This property provides a reference to an object defined elsewhere. This property and
     * all other properties are mutually exclusive. If other properties are defined in addition
     * to the ref property then the result is undefined.
     *
     * @return reference to an example
     **/
    String ref() default "";

}
```

Comment: Something like this is impossible with Java annotations. An annotation member has a predefined type and its value must conform to that type. That holds even for nested annotations or arrays of nested annotations. The `examples` member of `@Content` is of type `ExampleObject[]`, so you can't put any other annotation there.

Comment: @Ladicek Thanks a lot for your response. Is there a way I can replace the whole `@RequestBody`? so I will create the `CustomAnnotation` which consists of the elements from `@RequestBody` and replace the `@RequestBody` with `CustomAnnotation`. Is this possible?

Comment: That would theoretically be possible, but I have no idea whether it is actually supported.